# store.connect(imap.gmail.com, email, pass) can't connect to host, port imap.gmail.com, 993; timeout -1;

Tags: java, android, email, imap

I'm trying to create an app to send and receive emails, but whenever I run it in my emulator I get this error:
System.err: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; timeout -1; Using socket factory class javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

I have checked my firewall and it doesn't block any ports as far as I can tell.
This code is not in the main activity and the user email and password are transfered in extras.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
private Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LinearLayout Activity_Email = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_ActivityEmail);
    final LinearLayout Activity_Main = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_ActivityMain);

    final Button Button_NewEmail = findViewById(R.id.Button_NewEmail);
    final Button Button_UserProfile = findViewById(R.id.Button_UserProfile);
    final Button Button_Contacts = findViewById(R.id.Button_Contacts);
    final Button Button_ProfileFolders = findViewById(R.id.Button_ProfileFolders);
    final Button Button_Settings = findViewById(R.id.Button_Settings);

    ListView ListView_Emails = findViewById(R.id.ListView_EmailList);
    final EditText EditText_Filter = findViewById(R.id.EditText_EmailFilter);

    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    properties.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");

    properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    Session imapSession = Session.getInstance(properties);

    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("\nGetting store\n");
                Folder inbox;
                System.out.println("\nConnecting store\n");
                Store store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
                System.out.println("\nGetting folder\n");

                store.connect("imap.gmail.com", extras.getString("USER_EMAIL"), extras.getString("PASSWORD"));
                inbox=store.getFolder("Inbox");

                inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
             
                int numberOfEmails = messages.length;
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEmails; i++)
                {
                    List_Email new_email = new List_Email(Arrays.toString(messages[i].getFrom()), extras.getString("USER_EMAIL"), messages[i].getSubject(), messages[i].getContent().toString());
                    adapter.addList_Email(new_email);
                }
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                System.out.println("Prekid ovde Message\n");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Prekid ovde IO\n");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.run();

    ListView_Emails.setAdapter(adapter);

    ListView_Emails.setOnItemClickListener(new MyOnItemClickListener());


    Button_NewEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Emails_Activity.this, NewEmailActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("USER_EMAIL", extras.getString("USER_EMAIL"));
            intent.putExtra("PASSWORD", extras.getString("PASSWORD"));

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button_ProfileFolders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Emails_Activity.this, FoldersActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private class MyOnItemClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Bundle extras =getIntent().getExtras();
        List_Email mail = (List_Email) adapter.getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Emails_Activity.this, EmailActivity.class);

        String senderEmail = mail.Sender;
        String title = mail.Title;
        String content = mail.Content;

        intent.putExtra("Sender", senderEmail);
        intent.putExtra("Title", title);
        intent.putExtra("Content", content);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

In case it is needed, here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyEmailApp2">
    <activity android:name=".Emails_Activity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".EmailActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NewEmailActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FoldersActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the output in the Run tab when I get to the error while running the app on the emulator:

```
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xda01a360: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xda00f800)
I/chatty: uid=10135(com.example.myemailapp2) RenderThread identical 3 lines
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xda01a360: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xda00f800)
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xc299ab80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xda00fa50
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xda01a360: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xda00f800)
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@8318084
I/System.out: Getting store
I/System.out: Connecting store
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/System.out: Prekid ovde Message
W/System.err: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; timeout -1; Using socket factory class javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
  nested exception is:
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:735)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at com.example.myemailapp2.Emails_Activity$1.run(Emails_Activity.java:79)
    at com.example.myemailapp2.Emails_Activity.onCreate(Emails_Activity.java:107)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1106)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:235)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:352)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:217)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:124)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:128)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:758)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:693)
    ... 19 more
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xda01a360: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xda00f800)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xda01a360: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xda00f800)
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace in the question.

Comment: Please try connecting to Gmail IMAP from another machine on the same network (eg, using Apple Mail or Thunderbird or something), and see if it's possible.

Comment: The app doesn't crash because of this. The error gets cought in the try-catch. I can give you the logcat or all the stuff from the Run tab if you want.

Comment: Also, I use gmail on Chrome all the time as it's my main email. Is that good enough for the second comment?

Comment: No, gmail's web app does not use IMAP, so would not reflect network configuration problems.

Comment: I do have another PC with MS Outlook that is used with gmail accounts on the same network. I have also installed Thunderbird on my brothers PC and successfully connected with my gmail account on it. I've also added printlns in the code to show where the problem occurs and included the part in the Run tab where the error is printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your full stack trace shows the problem:

```
nested exception is:
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You may not do any networking on the main thread of your android application.  You must create a worker thread or similar and do it there.

The documentation for the [NetworkOnMainThread exception](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException) further describes the problem and links to a [document](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr) about why and how to deal with it.